# Get Current URL from a PHTML - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, phtml

I'm struggling trying to show the current URL from a PHTML in Magento 2.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's working for me

```
$this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true])
```

Also instead $this you can use $block.

Comment: Worked perfectly. =D

Comment: this is working perfectly. can we get the url without baseurl?

Answer (score 13):

```
$block->getRequest()->getUriString();
```

Answer (score 9):

To do so you will need to use a custom block from a module and do the following:

In Magento 2, you can use the `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` which is stored in an accessible variable `$_storeManager` for every class extending `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` so most of the block classes (`Template`, `Messages`, `Redirect` block types but not `Text` nor `TextList`).

This way in your block, you can create the following method to get the current URL:

```
public function getCurrentUrl() {
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl();
}
```

Once you've done that you can call the following in your template:

```
$block->getCurrentUrl();
```

Answer (score 1):

in block class:

```
    public function getCurrentUrl()
    {
        return $this->_urlBuilder->getCurrentUrl();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento Community 2.4

`your_file_name.phthml`

```
<?php
    /** @var Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
?>
<a href="<?= $block->getIdentifier(); ?>">My Page URL</a>
```