# How to use getUrl() function in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url

Can I call **Mage::getUrl()** directly using **$this->** in Magento2?

How can I use below code in Magento2?

```
$link = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$this_params));
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/118308/36463

Comment: You can feel free to close question after accepting answer from below.

Answer (score 21):

In a block, you can use `$this->getUrl()` with the parameters as you know them from Magento 1. In a template, use `$block->getUrl()` instead.

Outside blocks and templates, you need access to `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface`, so if it is not available yet in the current class, add it as a constructor parameter, assign it to `$this->urlBuilder`, then use `$this->urlBuilder->getUrl()`.

Comment: before add it as a constructor parameter check if $context has already an accessible instance of urlBuilder.

Comment: $context does have the urlInterface already. Should be able to do 
$this->_url->getUrl();

Answer (score 6):

You can simply call this method in  magento 2 using below way,

```
//define query array pass to url
    $query = ['str1' => 'value1', 'str2' => 'value2',];
    $link = $block->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => $query]);
```

You can also pass action value instead of `*/*/*` in above url, like **'customer/account/login'** as per your required action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in Magento 2 like

```
$block->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true])
```

Comment: how to use it in Block file? i am trying to get another controller in backUrl function.