# magento 2: get url query string

Tags: magento2, url

What is the magento 2 equivalent of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

I want to retrieve the full query string from the url and would like to do this using the framework's built in functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118305/get-current-url-from-a-phtml-magento-2

Comment: I don't think so, I am requesting for the query string while that question is asking for full URL.  The methods to achieve this appear to be different

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve this using the `getServer()` in the `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request` class

```
public function __construct
(
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request $request,
)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function execute()
{
    \Zend_Debug::dump($this->request->getServer('QUERY_STRING'));
    die;
}
```

If no argument is set, `$this->request->getServer()` will return complete `$_SERVER` array