# Magento 2 get Current page Browser url in phtml?

Tags: magento2, category, url, phtml

How can I get the current page URL from browser ?

Actually I wants to highlight the current category Name by giving some class or id to it.So for that based on browser URL I will put some condition for adding class to current category.

How can I achieve this in magento 2 ?

Comment: Do you want to add active class on current menu ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true])
```

Source: [Get Current URL from a PHTML - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118305/get-current-url-from-a-phtml-magento-2)