# How to get current Url value in magento 2

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1 we can the following function to get the referer url

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
```

How to get it in magento 2 I have used,

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
) {
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
}
echo $this->redirect->getRefererUrl();
echo $this->redirect->getRedirectUrl();
```

But it does not return the current Url value

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is your question `referer url` or `current url`?

Comment: I need current url

Comment: see https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/118307/4564

Comment: Its does not show current url i am in product edit page but it does not shows edit page url it shows only admin url

Comment: check this link --- https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-base-url-current-url-magento-2.html

Comment: I have tried but it does not give current url and i have used in my php file
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
then only gives a current url for me but is correct way to use?

Comment: Your question seems already answered here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118305/get-current-url-from-a-phtml-magento-2

Comment: yes i have tried but it does not give me current url